# How do I upload data from an excel file to an SQL db on a web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, datagrid, webforms

**Edit:** The assignment has changed drastically - sorry.

Now I have to write a web form that will take a CSV file and then display its contents in a grid. Still in C# and ASP.NET, but no SQL.

### C#

```c#
//This is the webform
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


namespace PatientImport
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((File1.PostedFile != null) && (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fn;
            try
            {
                if (fn.Substring(fn.Length - 3) == "csv" || fn.Substring(fn.Length - 3) == "CSV")
                {
                    File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                    Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Incorrect type. Choose a .csv file to upload.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
                //Note: Exception.Message returns a detailed message that describes the current exception. 
                //For security reasons, we do not recommend that you return Exception.Message to end users in 
                //production environments. It would be better to put a generic error message. 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Choose a .csv file to upload.");
        }

    }

}
}
```

### HTML

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"  Inherits="PatientImport.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
    <INPUT type=file id=File1 name=File1 runat="server" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="Submit1" value="Upload" runat="server" />
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would just have your application call a web method that loads the data into SQL once the file is uploaded.

Comment: What are you having a problem with? Uploading the file? Parsing the file?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modifed.

Comment: As @gunr2171 says, you should post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't help you without seeing some code, as we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: PLease look at it again, I added code, and the assignment changed.

Comment: @toothbrush, is this better?

Comment: @SavageHenry Yes, it is a lot better.

Comment: @toothbrush, sorry to keep bugging you, but can you help me then?

Comment: @SavageHenry Yes, I'll help. It'll have to be in the morning though, as it's now 1:30am here (in the UK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an ASP.NET grid, what you want is possible.

### HTML

```html
<asp:gridview id="CSVGridView" runat="server" />
```

### C#

```c#
//This is the webform
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace PatientImport {
    public partial class WebForm1: System.Web.UI.Page {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if ((File1.PostedFile != null) && (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)) {
                string fn = Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fn;

                try {
                    if (fn.Substring(fn.Length - 3) == "csv" || fn.Substring(fn.Length - 3) == "CSV") {
                        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                        Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");

                        // Read and parse the file
                        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(SaveLocation);
                        string pattern = "\"(?<data>.*?)\"|(^|,)(?<data>[^,\r\n]*)";
                        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ECMAScript;

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data[0], pattern, options);

                        foreach (Match match in matches) {
                            dt.Columns.Add(match.Groups["data"].Value, typeof(string));
                        }

                        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++) {
                            matches = Regex.Matches(data[i], pattern, options);

                            List<string> row = new List<string>();

                            foreach (Match match in matches) {
                                row.Add(match.Groups["data"].Value);
                            }

                            dt.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
                        }

                        CSVGridView.DataSource = dt;
                        CSVGridView.DataBind();
                    } else {
                        Response.Write("Incorrect type. Choose a .csv file to upload.");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    //Note: Exception.Message returns a detailed message that describes the current exception. 
                    //For security reasons, we do not recommend that you return Exception.Message to end users in 
                    //production environments. It would be better to put a generic error message. 
                }
            } else {
                Response.Write("Choose a .csv file to upload.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

I'm using the regular expression `"(?<data>.*?)"|(^|,)(?<data>[^,\r\n]*)`:

1. `"(?<data>.*?)"` matches a quote, any character naught or more times (the `?` makes it non-greedy, so it will stop matching when it reaches the other quote) and a quote.

   `".*?"` would match all of `"abc"`, so we select only the `abc` part by creating a capturing group (`(?<data>.*?)`).
2. `(^|,)(?<data>[^,\r\n]*)` matches either the beginning of a line or a comma, and then any character except a comma, a carriage return or a new line naught or more times.

   Again, `(?<data>` starts a capturing group called `data` so that we don't also get the comma (if there is one).

Then, in the code, I use `match.Groups["data"].Value` to get the value of the named capturing group `data`.

For the flags, I uses `ECMAScript` so that I can use ECMAScript-defined semantics. The other flags are required for using the `ECMAScript` flag: `Compiled`, `Multiline` and `IgnoreCase`.

Comment: Okay @toothbrush, so its telling me that the Add methods inside of the two foreach loops cannot accept match.Groups["data"] as a string.

Comment: @SavageHenry OK, I think I've corrected it now. Will you try it again, please?

Comment: YES! it worked thanks! Would you mind explaining to me what the string pattern and RegexOptions do? @toothbrush

Comment: @SavageHenry I added an explanation to my post. If it doesn't clarify what it does, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

`Should the program be separate from the web form application that accepts the file?` - It depends on your need. You can keep it separate or your web application can do this.

`How do I get the program to run on the web server right when a file is uploaded?` - If this is done by your web application, you will straight away do it once the upload is complete. If you decide to have your desktop application to do a transfer to db, use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to watch the directory to which you upload the Excel files on the web server.